# Table of contents : different page styles for first and subsequent pages

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, backgrounds

It's my first question. I read only answers and comments usually. Its work before =).

So, question is how to use different styles for first and subsequent pages of TOC.

I've written different styles with frame (`framebig` for first and `framesmall` for subsequent pages ). The frame is drawn using `tikz` and `background` packages.  I tried use `\thispagestyle{framebig}` for `\tableofcontents` command, but it didn't work (I don't know why).

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, hidelinks]{book}
\usepackage[width=17cm, left=3cm, top=1cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage[scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1,color=black!100]{background}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% My page styles with frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpagestyle{framesmall}{
\newgeometry{width=17cm, left=3cm, top=1cm, bottom=2.5cm}
\backgroundsetup{%
contents={\SMALLFRAME}
 }
}

\newpagestyle{framebig}{
\newgeometry{width=17cm, left=3cm, top=1cm, bottom=5cm}
\backgroundsetup{%
contents={\BIGFRAME}
 }
}

%    SMALLFRAME command
\newcommand{\SMALLFRAME}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 18.4cm,
    minimum height = 28.5cm] (frame) at ($(current page.south east)+(-0.6cm,0.6cm)$) {};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 1cm,
    minimum height = .8cm] (page) at ($(current page.south east)+(-0.6cm,0.6cm)$) {\thepage};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 1cm,
    minimum height = .7cm] (pagename) at ($(page.north east)+(0cm,-0.04cm)$) {\small Page};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 11cm,
    minimum height = 1.5cm] (smallframe) at ($(page.south west)+(0.04cm,0cm)$) {pagestyle\{framesmall\}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

%    BIGFRAME command
\newcommand{\BIGFRAME}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 18.4cm,
    minimum height = 28.5cm] (frame) at ($(current page.south east)+(-0.6cm,0.6cm)$) {};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 2cm,
    minimum height = .5cm] (pages) at ($(frame.south east)+(0cm,-0.03cm)$) {\pageref{LastPage}};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 2cm,
    minimum height = .5cm] (pagesname) at ($(pages.north east)+(0cm,-0.03cm)$) {Pages};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 1.5cm,
    minimum height = .5cm] (page) at ($(pages.south west)+(0.03cm,-0.0cm)$) {\thepage}; %
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 1.5cm,
    minimum height = .5cm] (pagename) at ($(pagesname.south west)+(0.03cm,-0.0cm)$) {Page};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 18.4cm,
    minimum height = 5.5cm] (smallframe) at ($(frame.south east)+(0.0cm,-0.03cm)$) {pagestyle\{framebig\}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% END of style's block
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{framebig}
\tableofcontents

\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}

\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}



\end{document}
```

Is there a way to solve this problem using the given libraries, or are additional ones required?

I would like to see the table of contents as shown in the pictures below.

[image]

I will be glad to receive answers and comments to my question.

P. S. How to remove page numbers that come with standard design (marked with a red circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix the `background` package settings and the `titleps` pagestyle settings.
They both can achieve your layout individually but in a different way. You shouldn't mix them together. IMHO, `titleps` is more likely the tool you should use. Because you could also set the header contents by using it. Also, you ask how to remove page numbers as well in the question, so this is where `titleps` package will be useful. In the following example, I will use `titleps` to achieve your goal,  and header is set to empty at the moment.

For the page margin changes and page style changes in the bigframe page and restore to default for following pages. You need use the `afterpage` package and redefine the `\part` and `\chapter` command. Put `\afterpage{\newgeometry{width=17cm, left=3cm, top=1cm, bottom=6cm}\restoregeometry}` at the beginning of these two command defintion. This will make the chapter (also influence table of contents, because it is star version of chapter) and part (I assume you want the part page also have big frame layout) page with new geometry and set back to default for the following pages. By default, there will be a `\thispagestyle{plain}` in these two commands definition. So, your need to change them to `\thispagestyle{framebig}` in order to change the page style for chapter and part page as well.

For the new page style definition, you should take a look the official [document](https://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titleps.pdf) of this package. The meaning of `\newpagestyle` is to set the new header and footer for this page style, the way you define it is just execute some commands and ignore the footer and header contents. That is not what you should do by using this command. There are total 12 header and footer contents that you can set:

> `\sethead[⟨even-left⟩][⟨even-center⟩][⟨even-right⟩] {⟨odd-left⟩}{⟨odd-center⟩}{⟨odd-right⟩}`

> `\setfoot[⟨even-left⟩][⟨even-center⟩][⟨even-right⟩] {⟨odd-left⟩}{⟨odd-center⟩}{⟨odd-right⟩}`

You can use any of these locations to include your `tikz` code, because you use the `remember picture` and `overlay` option and put the node on absolute position according to the page node. What I did is only set the ⟨odd-left⟩ and ⟨even-left⟩ foot contents to be the `tikz` code (`\SMALLFRAME` or `\SMALLFRAME`) and leave the others as empty (seems like you don't want any headers).

I remove all unnecessary packages. And tweak the your `tikz` code a little bit to finish the drawing without `calc` library. By using `shift={(-0.6cm,0.6cm)` option you are allowed to put the node at a location relative to a page node. And `outer sep=0pt` option, make you don't need to consider the line width of your nodes when position them

Here is the final code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, hidelinks]{book}
\usepackage[width=17cm, left=3cm, top=1cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Don't need any more
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% My page styles with frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
  \afterpage{\newgeometry{width=17cm, left=3cm, top=1cm, bottom=6cm}\restoregeometry}
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{framebig}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\renewcommand\chapter{%
\afterpage{\newgeometry{width=17cm, left=3cm, top=1cm, bottom=6cm}\restoregeometry}%
\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
    \thispagestyle{framebig}%
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\newpagestyle{framesmall}{
\sethead[][][]{}{}{}
\setfoot[\SMALLFRAME][][]
{\SMALLFRAME}{}{}
}

\newpagestyle{framebig}{
\sethead[][][]{}{}{}
\setfoot[\BIGFRAME][][]
{\BIGFRAME}{}{}
}

%    SMALLFRAME command
\newcommand{\SMALLFRAME}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 18.4cm,
    minimum height = 28.5cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    shift={(-0.6cm,0.6cm)}
    ] (frame) at (current page.south east) {};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 1.2cm,
    minimum height = .8cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    shift={(-0.6cm,0.6cm)}
    ] (page) at (current page.south east) {\thepage};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 1.2cm,
    minimum height = .7cm,outer sep=0pt] (pagename) at (page.north east) {\small Page};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 11cm,
    minimum height = 1.5cm,outer sep=0pt] (smallframe) at (page.south west) {pagestyle\{framesmall\}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

%    BIGFRAME command
\newcommand{\BIGFRAME}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 18.4cm,
    minimum height = 28.5cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    shift={(-0.6cm,0.6cm)}
    ] (frame) at (current page.south east) {};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 2cm,
    minimum height = .5cm,
    outer sep=0pt
    ] (pages) at (frame.south east) {\pageref{LastPage}};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 2cm,
    minimum height = .5cm,
    outer sep=0pt
    ] (pagesname) at (pages.north east) {Pages};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 1.5cm,
    minimum height = .5cm,
    outer sep=0pt
    ] (page) at (pages.south west) {\thepage}; %
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 1.5cm,
    minimum height = .5cm,
    outer sep=0pt
    ] (pagename) at (pagesname.south west) {Page};
  \node[rectangle,
    draw = black,
    line width = 1pt,
    anchor=south east,
    minimum width = 18.4cm,
    minimum height = 5.5cm,
    outer sep=0pt
    ] (smallframe) at (frame.south east) {pagestyle\{framebig\}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% END of style's block
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% initial the common pagestyle %
% for regular page             %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{framesmall}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{part}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{section}
\section{section}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% create some dummy toc entries %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{tempcn}
\loop
\ifnum\value{tempcn}<21
\stepcounter{tempcn}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Testing}\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Testing}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Testing}
\repeat
\end{document}
```

> Output:

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! (LaTex too!)
Thank you for your complete answer on all aspects of my problem!